# C Language: char array issues and warnings by eclipse

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I just returned to develop in C over eclipse and im having big issues im not sure how to solve, dont remember i used to have such when developing before. anyway i'll point u to 2 issues (i made my example easy-to-post in here):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int change_array(char *str, char *a[]) {
    a[0] = "changed [0]";
    if (fgets(str, 200, stdin) != NULL) {
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char str[200];
    char a[15][200];
    change_array(str, a);
    printf("a[0]: %s\n", a[0]);
    printf("str: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

1. getting a warning in line "change_array(str, a)": **passing argument 2 of ‘change_array’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]** - why??
2. after running my 'doing-nothing' code sample output is:

   - some-value
   - a[0]: � <------- wired characters appear
   - str: some-value

Comment: Try to use strcpy to assign value to a string. strcpy(a[0], "changed [0]")

Comment: posting the full warning which is: 
../test.c:13:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘change_array’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../test.c:3:5: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[200]’

Comment: thanks marcadian but i'd like to understand whats the issue exactly, giving the value hard coded is not what i ment.

Comment: Change your function header to int change_array(char *str, char a[][200]) {

Comment: Iv'e just tried that, code is not compiling at line: a[0] = "changed [0]"; – i assume that's because it looks like im trying to re-size the array of chars, but what if i want to set it to less than 200 characters

Comment: use strcpy to assign string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here... `int change_array(char *str, char *a[])`

The dimension of `a` is undefined, so it doesn't know how far to step each `*a` and `a` is an array of pointers to char. However, you are passing in an array of arrays of 200 char. Thus the incompatible types error.

I believe your issue goes away with...

`int change_array(char *str, char (*a)[200])`

in which case `a` is a pointer to an array of 200 chars and the compiler now knows how far to step each index of `a`

Comment: Iv'e just tried that, code is not compiling at line: a[0] = "changed [0]";

Comment: +1 (on both the code, and the comment to use proper string copying)

Comment: Ok that fixed that, but im feeling pretty confused :|

Comment: check my main post, marcadian suggested changing the function signature to: (.., char a[][200]), is that exactly as (.., char (*a)[200])?

Comment: They are similar. Keep in mind that arrays always decompose into a pointer to the type. So `char a[][200]` decomposes to `char (*a)[200]` -- there are, however, some C compilers that may choke on `char a[][200]` though I suspect they would be very few and far between.

Comment: I hate * notation :) so I prefer [], sorry if it's causing confusion

Comment: hmm, i understand, so whats syntax fits a case when i want to send the array as a 'value-type' from main to the change_array method so it won't actually work on it's pointer?

Comment: They are interchangeable. Use the one you prefer. The `a[][200]` form would prevent modification of the pointer to `a` that would be possible in the `(*a)[200]` variant if you are afraid of accidentally modifying the pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your extended explanation :-) ! I wish i wud post my questions 3 hours ago (before wasting my time)

Comment: "The dimension of a is undefined, so it doesn't know how far to step each *a" This is completely irrelevant. `a` is a pointer to pointer to char. It has no "internal dimension". The fundamental issue (as you later describe) is that a pointer to pointer is completely different than a pointer to an array (there is no pointer in the program to be pointing to anyway).

Comment: can anyone please clarify how do i set an array of char* arrays? i.e: i'd like to define 'a' as:
a[0] = {"one","two",.."}
a[1] = {"one","two",.."}
...